# Simple Programming Syntax

Tags: object, properties, member

In the following sentence taken from Mozilla: "The **Window.history** read-only property returns a reference to the **History** object..."

Can anyone tell me why Window.history is a property?

I thought "**window.**" would be the object and "**.history**" would be the property. But instead "**Window.history**" is the entire property that "references" the "History" object.

I am new to programming, but I thought the correct syntax would be "object.member" and in this case the object would be "**Window.**" and "**.history**" would be property.

What would then be the correct syntax of "**window.history**" if "**window.history**" is itself a property?

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that in many programming languages, the .-operator accesses a member of an object or class.

While the statement you cite is much more vague than actual code, I believe it should be read:

> The object **Window** has a member **history** that references a **History** object.

I.e. in Java it could look like this:

```
public class Window {
    private History history;

    public History getHistory() {
        return history;
    }
}
```

Properties of objects are typically variables, that may themselves reference objects, thus the ambiguity of the sentence.

Hope this helps.